# Razor View, How to disable @htmlEdittorFor or Make it ready depending on Model Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper, disabled-input

I would like to conditionally disable this button, or make it read only so the user can just see the data displaying in the box or text but not being able to edit whatsoever, i have tried many steps towards this issue but nothing seems to be working if you look in my code below.

can anyone advice me or come up with a solution for this matter.
thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZcBd.png)

```
<div class="inline-block-side">
    @if (Model.Promotion.PromotionID == 209)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle) 
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle)
        </div>              
        <div class="editor-field" title="The name of the Promotion"  @((Model.Promotion.PromotionID == 209) ? "disabled" : "")>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle)
        </div>                    
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Promotion.ArtworkDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" title="The date the Artwork is to be recieved by">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Promotion.ArtworkDate, "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", new { @id = "ArtworkDate", @class = "date" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Promotion.ArtworkDate)  
        </div>
```

Comment: What button are you referring to? And what is not working? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? (and remove the invalid `@((Model.Promotion.PromotionID == 209) ? "disabled" : "")` code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke check my post again i included a image as example.  im refering to all the html edit for and text box, what happen is when the user open the page textboxes already generated the data and it allows the user to edit the data and change. now i want is when the proomotion title is equal to 209 i do not want the user to edit the data in the text i would just like the user to just see the data but not being able to edit the data. does that that make sense to you now?

Comment: That's what the code in the `if` block does - for that one property at least - just add `DisplayNameFor() and `DisplayFor() for each property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it will be best to post the code you talking about as im doin what you advice me and still getting the same issue by posting the code maybe it will highlight something that im doing wrong my code

Comment: What 'issue'? You still have not explained what your expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Html.DisplayFor to solve your problems, or you can user jquery enable, disable attributes to make textboxe readOnly

Comment: i solved my problem by write some jquery function, thanks